# Windows 10 Kiosk Mode fails with 0xc00ce223

Tags: xml, windows, windows-10, provisioning, kiosk

I used this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/lock-down-windows-10-to-specific-apps to create a Provision Package.

The XML File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AssignedAccesConfiguration 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAcces/2017/config" 
  xmlns:rs5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AssignedAccess/201810/config"
>
  <Profiles>
    <Profile Id="{e7c8ea73-a26c-4801-9c72-e79c5127b7b3}">
      <AllAppsList>
        <AllowedApps>
          <App DesktopAppPath="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" rs5:AutoLaunch="true" />
          <App DesktopAppPath="C:\Windows\explorer.exe" />
          <App DesktopAppPath="%WinDir%\system32\mspaint.exe" />
          <App DesktopAppPath="%WinDir%\system32\calc.exe" />
          <App AppUserModelId="Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
          <App AppUserModelId="Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
        </AllowedApps>
      </AllAppsList>
      <rs5:FileExplorerNamespaceRestrictions>
        <rs5:AllowedNamespace Name="Downloads" />
      </rs5:FileExplorerNamespaceRestrictions>
      <StartLayout>
        <![CDATA[<LayoutModificationTemplate 
          xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout" 
          xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout" 
          Version="1" 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
          >
          <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
          <DefaultLayoutOverride>
            <StartLayoutCollection>
              <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="6">
                <start:Group Name="Internet">
                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="308046B0AF4A39CB" />
                </start:Group>
                <start:Group Name="Windows">
                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{F38BF404-1D43-42F2-9305-67DE0B28FC23}\explorer.exe" />
                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="1" DesktopApplicationID="{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\calc.exe" />
                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="2" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\mspaint.exe" />
                  <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="3" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="{F38BF404-1D43-42F2-9305-67DE0B28FC23}\notepad.exe" />
                </start:Group>
              </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
            </StartLayoutCollection>
          </DefaultLayoutOverride>
        </LayoutModificationTemplate>
        ]]>
      </StartLayout>
      <Taskbar ShowTaskbar="true" />
    </Profile>
  </Profiles>
  <Configs>
    <Config>
      <Account>
        Guest
      </Account>
      <DefaultProfile Id="{e7c8ea73-a26c-4801-9c72-e79c5127b7b3}" />
    </Config>
  </Configs>
</AssignedAccesConfiguration>
```

But if I run this with PowerShell I get the following result:

```
IsInstalled     : True
PackageID       : 865bdb2a-51a0-46ec-9773-5f821cfc975c
PackageName     : LibraryKioskMode
PackagePath     : C:\Users\admin\Documents\Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer
                  (WICD)\LibraryKioskMode\LibraryKioskMode.ppkg
Description     :
Rank            : 0
Altitude        : 5000
Version         : 1.5
OwnerType       : ITAdmin
Notes           :
LastInstallTime : 12/2/2019 3:42:32 PM
Result          : 0__Accounts_Users_Guest.provxml
                        Category:LocalAccount
                        LastResult:Success
                        Message:Provisioning succeeded
                        NumberOfFailures:0 (0x0)

                  1__AssignedAccess_MultiAppAssignedAccessSettings.provxml
                        Category:UxLockdown
                        LastResult:Error -1072897501 (0xC00CE223)
                        Message:Provisioning failed
                        NumberOfFailures:1 (0x1)
```

I have searched for the error code 0xC00CE223 and it means that I have more than one root element in my xml file. But the XML Validator I have used doesn't show me any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your root element (`AssignedAccesConfiguration` should be `AssignedAccessConfiguration`).